# How to do inhereted empty constructor when Base class has constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, constructor, filehelpers

i.e. I've got a class Box with properties length, height, width and constructor "Box(int witdth, int height, int length)". Got an inhereted class ProductBox with property Name.
I've also got a .csv file which I parse to ProductBox with FileHelpers library, so my constructor's empty.
For now I can't inherete ProductBox from Box, because Box has not-empty constructor, and in FileHelpers the constructor's empty. Is there a way to inherete ProductBox from Box?

```
class Box
{
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Length;

    public Box(int width, int height, int length)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Length = length;
    }
}

class ProductBox : Box
{
    string Name;
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Length;
    public static ProductBox[] GetInfo(string filePath)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ProductBox>();
        var result = engine.ReadFile(filePath);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, I think you are going about it the wrong way. While you might be able to hack something together to solve your constructor problem, you are trying to use the `Box` class for two incompatible uses. Instead you should have two separate classes.

FileHelpers is a library for describing csv files so that you can import them easily. You should have a `BoxFileSpec` for describing your file. It's really not a proper C# class - it may have: dummy fields to represent unused columns; lots of attributes `[FieldNullValue]`, `[FieldQuoted]`, `[FieldConverter]`; etc. It works best with public fields (a FileHelpers limitation which is not C# best practice), etc. It is a *convenience* syntax for describing the import file. It should **not** include any logic or special constructors.

Then you can have a clean best-practices `Box` class which has your specialized constructors and additional logic, properties, methods, whatever.

Then you use a `FileHelperEngine<BoxFileSpec>` to read the records into an array and map it to an enumerable of `Box` (via Linq or a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)).

Something like:

```
/// A 'real' class. Add methods, getters, setters, whatever.
/// FileHelpers doesn't use this class.
class Box
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public Box(int width, int height, int length)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Length = length;
    }
}

/// A 'real' class. Add methods, getters, setters, whatever.
/// FileHelpers doesn't use this class.
class ProductBox : Box
{
    public ProductBox(int width, int height, int length) 
        : base(width, height, length)
    { }

    public int Name { get; set; }
}

/// This is the class FileHelpers will use
/// This class describes the CSV file only. Stick to whatever
/// syntax conventions are required by FileHelpers.
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
class ProductBoxFileSpec
{
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    public int Width;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    public int Height;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    // Handle non-US formats such as , decimal points
    // convert from inches to centimetres? 
    // you get the idea...
    [FieldConverter(MyCustomizedLengthConverter)] 
    public int Length;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string SomeDummyExtraCSVColumn;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ProductBoxFileSpec>();
        var productBoxRecords = engine.ReadFile(filePath);
        var productBoxes = productBoxRecords
            .Select(x => new ProductBox(x.Width, x.Height, x.Length) { Name = x.Name });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

If your base class provides a parametered constructor, you can't provide a parameterless one in a derived class unless you redefine the base class to also have a parameterless constructor. Where would the values come from?

If your base was actually a `struct` instead, it would be possible because of the default parameterless constructor defined by `struct`s.

You could chain your constructor as described by hl3mukkel, where your derived class passes the constructed values. You could also do something like this:

```
class ProductBox : Box
{
    string Name;

    public ProductBox()
        :base(0,0,0)
    {
    }
}
```

If you wanted to provide the defaults yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it inherits from it you can just do constructor chaining

```
public class Box 
{
    int Width;
    int Height;
    int Length;

    public Box(int width, int height, int length)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Length = length;
    }
}

public class ProductBox : Box
{
    string Name;

    public ProductBox(string Name, int width, int height, int length)
        : base(width, height, length)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public static ProductBox[] GetInfo(string filePath)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ProductBox>();
        var result = engine.ReadFile(filePath);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: wait. the original question is how to do a parameter less constructor in the child class. Where is that?

Comment: I can't create ProductBox with parameters, since I'm using a FileHelpers library and it requires a parameterless constructor. If I do so, there'll be a error.